# DCOS 1.8 cluster built on IBM z (s390x) platform does not show stats on DCOS-UI

Tags: dcos

We are in process of porting the DCOS on IBM z platform (s390x architecture).  So far we have succeeded in building v1.8 from source and have managed to install the cluster having 3 masters and 2 agents configuration.

The Marathon is accessible on port 8080 and we are able to deploy applications on the cluster.

However, the DCOS UI  (`http://<master ip>/`)
 does not display any statistics about the cluster like for e.g. the Dashboard shows 0% for all three parameters like 'CPU allocation', 'Memory Allocation' and 'Disk Allocation'.
The System/Components health check displays all services as Healthy except dcos-signal.
DCOS-CLI is able to get information relating to our apps in Marathon.
However following command fails with following error message:

```
dcos package list
```

> URL [http:///package/list] is unreachable:
>   ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

We are looking for pointers to debug this issue.  Could you please let us know any areas/services/configurations in the DCOS cluster that need to be checked?

Comment: Interesting, could you by any chance come to the dcos slack channel (chat.dcos.io). This seems to require a more interactive communication ;-)